# Accessing Json objects

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

```
{"Kind": {
"Food": {
    "color": "0",
    "size": "31",
    "shape": "round"
},
"Drink": {
    "color": "0",
    "size": "34",
    "shape": "square"
},
"Condiments": {
    "color": "0",
    "size": "52",
    "shape": "rectangle"
}
```

Hi I have this in a JSON  and I'm trying to put it in a table in it would just show the Kind for example Food and shape referring to round.

Do you guys know any way on how I can extract it?

Before it was easier for me to get the data because the format of the JSON

```
 var obj = [
{
    "Kind": "Food",
    "shape": "round"
}, {
    "Kind": "Drink",
    "shape": "square"
}, {
    "Kind": "Condiments",
    "shape": "rectangle"
}]
```

Calling it was easy as

```
<td>{{obj.Kind}}</td><td>{obj.shape}}</td>
```

Now I'm not really sure on how to do it with the new json format..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your problem the following is the answer for your question .

Your html code like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th> <th>Shape</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key ,value) in list.Kind">
            <td>{{key}}</td><td>{{value.shape}}</td>
       </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

After that your javascript like this

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){

         $scope.list ={"Kind": {
    "Food": {
        "color": "0",
        "size": "31",
        "shape": "round"
    },
    "Drink": {
        "color": "0",
        "size": "34",
        "shape": "square"
    },
    "Condiments": {
        "color": "0",
        "size": "52",
        "shape": "rectangle"
    }
         }
                      };

    });
```

Finally the output is

**Type**     **Shape**

Condiments   rectangle

Drink        square

Food         round

Comment: Did great help!! Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 1):

[ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) can iterate over objects. Assuming your JSON is stored in $scope.data:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(type, attributes) in data.Kind">
  <td>{{ type }}</td><td>{{ attributes.shape }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you html code would be like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in list"><td>{{obj.Kind}}</td><td>{{obj.shape}}</td></tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

JS code would be like this

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
     $scope.list = [
        {
            "Kind": "Food",
            "shape": "round"
        }, {
            "Kind": "Drink",
            "shape": "square"
        }, {
            "Kind": "Condiments",
            "shape": "rectangle"
        }]
});
```

if you want a working code then please got [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/x8jeufz3/1/).

Comment: You must have misunderstood the question. Well I'm using now the first block of code I pasted on the question :) The second block of code was the one I was using before hehe Thanks anyway

Comment: the response in the first block does not have any order. so if you do not what to expect you will need to create array from object and then order it. If you do know what to expect then you can create a template on client side .

Comment: i updated the code with the assumption that you know the structure of the response. 
http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/x8jeufz3/6/
@Anid Monsur's response is very good and i think it will work.

Comment: It does work i updated my answer and added his code as well. the updated link is jsfiddle.net/chandings/x8jeufz3/7

Answer (score 0):

When you get the response from service: (Assuming response)

```
response = { "Kind": {
                    "Food": {
                    "color": "0",
                    "size": "31",
                    "shape": "round"
             },
               "Drink": {
               "color": "0",
               "size": "34",
              "shape": "square"
             },
              "Condiments": {
              "color": "0",
              "size": "52",
              "shape": "rectangle"
             } 
          }
       }

$scope.Condiments = response.Kind.Condiments;
$scope.Drinks = response.Kind.Drink;
```

And on front end you can access that object like below

```
  {{Condiments.size}}
  {{ Drinks.size }}
```

Or you can use the object iteration on ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array out of the json object that you have and work normally like you were doing before

[Example Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7lcVhvcRse7xjPO8btIR?p=preview)

Code Snippet:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = {"Kind": {
      "Food": {
          "color": "0",
          "size": "31",
          "shape": "round"
      },
      "Drink": {
          "color": "0",
          "size": "34",
          "shape": "square"
      },
      "Condiments": {
          "color": "0",
          "size": "52",
          "shape": "rectangle"
      }
    }
  }

  var listKeys = Object.keys($scope.list);
  $scope.arrayOfKind = [];
  var kindObj;
  for (var kind in $scope.list[listKeys]) {
    kindObj = {};
    kindObj.kind = kind;
    kindObj.shape = $scope.list[listKeys][kind].shape;
    kindObj.size = $scope.list[listKeys][kind].size;
    $scope.arrayOfKind.push(kindObj);
  }
});
```